# How to store post_id from the Post model| Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

First of all I am new to Laravel. I am trying to build a lil social network. I do have a post user and comments model. On Post model I have a hasMany relationship between post and comment.
 I do have a store() method that saves the user comment on a post:

```
public function store(Post $post)
{

     $this->validate(request(), ['body'=> 'required|min:2']);

    Comment::create([
            'body' => request('body'),
            'post_id'=>$post->id
    ]);

    return back();

}
```

my post model:

```
 <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    //

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'body'];

    public function comment()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to save the post_id from the model itself and refactor the code in a better way ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the controller it's dealing with validation, storing and redirecting. U could refactor your code by creating a method on your `Post` model and then call it on the controller.

Since u have a hasMany relationship between a post and a comment you could call the relationship as a method so that way u store the comment on the current `post_id`. Like so:

```
public function storeComment($body)
{
    $this->comment()->create(compact('body'));
}
```

then u call it on ur constructor:

```
public function store(Post $post)
{
        $this->validate(request(), ['body'=> 'required|min:2']);

        $post->addComment(request('body'));

        return back();  
}
```